What exactly is the role of Gilchrist in history of Hindvi?
Recently there has been an influx of polemics on Reddit/4chan etc., saying that "Hindi is just Sanskritized Urdu", or "the language of Hindustani is a gift of invaders" or something like "Sanskritized Hindi was created by Gilchrist", etc. Of course, all these posts are made in bad faith, which is why I picked up a book "Persian Influence on Hindi" by Hardev Bahri (a respected Hindi scholar and dictionarist). The book in its introductory chapters lays down a history of the Hindvi. And pointed out the existence of Hindustani before Islamic invasion.
However, what it says about Gilchrist is strikingly opposite to what is said by the polemicists. While polemics deem Gilchrist to be the source of Sanskritized Hindi, Bahri said that he (Gilchrist) was actually the proponents of "Persianized Urdu". He writes:

"[Gilchrist] and a large number of British imperialists like
Shakespeare, Fallon, Piatts and Duncan Forbes have written their
Hindustani dictionaries and grammars either in Persian scripts or in
Roman scripts with a biased disregard of Sanskritic and popular
forms. For instance, in their grammatical works the technical terms -- isma (not naam) for noun, sifat (not vishesan) for adjective, harfa (not akshar) for letter, jam`a (not bahuvacan) for plural), -- have been freely employed."

When I searched for a similar view on the internet, I found nothing, further fueling this identity crisis of mine with this stark difference in opinions about Gilchrist's role.
Anyways, I come here to finally extinguish this torment. Please tell what exactly is the role of Gilchrist in making of Hindi? Is it over-exaggerated? Or was Gilchrist singlehandedly responsible for the idea of a Sanskritized Hindi (in which case I'll be damned F)? Thanks!
External links/sources:-

Persian Influence on Hindi, by Dr. Hardev Bahri, pp. 14
Hindi Was Devised by a Scottish Linguist of the East India Company, It Can Never be India's National Language

